# Popover arrow not the same color as the viewcontroller background

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, popover

The title says it all really. I have a view controller connected to a button as a popover. The view controller's background color is grey, but the color of the arrow pointing to the button is white. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 41):

Here's how I get around it:

```
popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentViewController];
popover.backgroundColor = contentViewController.view.backgroundColor;
```

This matches the popover to the color of the content's background.

Answer (score 19):

for ios 9.0 +
(cpvc is your ViewController)

```
cpvc.popoverPresentationController.backgroundColor = cpvc.view.backgroundColor;
```

Comment: This is available in iOS 8.0+, and can be called from the prepareForSegue in the presenting VC.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using IOS7 sdk?

maybe you can try:

```
[popover setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

and make sure you set background color of the content view controller to white.

Answer (score 3):

swift 4.2

```
navController?.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = .black
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in iOS7 (ugly white "arrow"). This seems to fix it for me.  UIPopoverController does not support setBackgroundColor pre iOS7, thus the check.

```
if ([popoverController respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:)])
{
   [popoverController setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```